# PHP session upload progrees undefined key

Tags: php, jquery, file, codeigniter, file-upload

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: formdata,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    }, 
    beforeSend:function(e, d){
        setInterval(function(){
            $.post(url, {f:'upload_progress'}, function(data){
                console.log(data);
        });
    }, 1);
}, ....
```

**PHP**

```
  if($this->input->post('f')){
      var_dump($_SESSION[session.upload_progress.prefix .  
      $_POST[session.upload_progress.name]]);
 }
 if($this->input->post('filename')){
      // upload
      ...
 }
```

and I get an error undefined key.
If I check the session upload progress name:

```
echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.name");
```

I see its name `"f"`.
Where I am wrong and how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
var_dump($_SESSION[session.upload_progress.prefix .  
      $_POST[session.upload_progress.name]]);
```

to this line:

```
var_dump($_SESSION[(session.upload_progress.prefix).($_POST[session.upload_progress.name])]);
```

Let me know if that worked for you.

Comment: Use of undefined constant session - assumed 'session'

Comment: @gdfgdfg paste your code that initiates the session constant, since that seems to be where the error originates. If you don't have that code anywhere, then that is what is missing.

Comment: The session is started by defafult (I am using CodeIgniter), I checked and it is on, shoud I must do something other ?